# How to call slimerJs in a python?

Tags: python, selenium, slimerjs

All the code I read on slimer seems java based.

I read [here](https://docs.slimerjs.org/nightly/configuration.html#about-proxy-configuration) that you can run slimer as a selenium driver but I have no idea how to set it in python.

I tried:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('F:\\slimer\\slimerjs.bat',service_args=service_args)
```

It was a long shot but I read that slimer is made to accept phantom code so I thought that might be the case. But not surprisingly that didn't work.

So any idea how to set it as the driver in the script? The link above just shows the command line arguments so I don't know how it would 'plug in' to the code in my python project?